# Python equivalent of Matlab textscan

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, textscan

I'm working with transferring some Matlab code to Python.  I'm relatively new to Python and am unsure of a Python equivalent of Matlab's [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) method.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By not telling us what Matlab's `textscan()` does, you may be limiting yourself to receiving answers from only the people who know both Matlab and Python.

Comment: @kindall MATLAB's `textscan()` does more or less acts like a `sscanf` in C.

Comment: @kindall Here's a link to a description of Matlab's `textscan()` method [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're translating Matlab to Python, I'll assume you're already using NumPy.

In that case, you can use [`np.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) (if no values are missing) or [`np.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy-genfromtxt) (if there are missing values: I'm not sure whether Matlab's `textscan` handles that).

Give us a few more details if you need more help!

Answer (score 5):

Example of conversion of MATLAB's `textscan` to Python + NumPy's [`np.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt):

Let our data file `results.csv` contain:

```
0.6236,sym2,1,5,10,10
0.6044,sym2,2,5,10,10
0.548,sym2,3,5,10,10
0.6238,sym2,4,5,10,10
0.6411,sym2,5,5,10,10
0.7105,sym2,6,5,10,10
0.6942,sym2,7,5,10,10
0.6625,sym2,8,5,10,10
0.6531,sym2,9,5,10,10
```

Matlab code:

```
fileID = fopen('results.csv');
d = textscan(fileID,'%f %s %d %d %d %d', 'delimiter',',');
fclose(fileID);
```

Python + NumPy code:

```
fd = open('results2.csv','r')    
d = np.loadtxt(fd,
           delimiter=',',
           dtype={'names': ('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'),
           'formats': ('float', 'S4', 'i4', 'i4', 'i4', 'i4')})
fd.close()
```

For more info on types, see [Data type objects (dtype)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

Answer (score 4):

you have to look for Numpy and py2mat. If my understanding of textscan() is correct you could just use `open()`

Answer (score 1):

If your results are more complicated than simple delimited text, such as if there are other, useless bits of text mixed in, then you can use Numpy's [`fromregex`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html#numpy.fromregex) function to replace `textscan`.  `fromregex` lets you read in based on a regular expression, with groups (parts surrounded by `()`) as the values.

So for example say you have lines like this:

```
field1 is 1, field 2 is 5 to 6.6
field1 is 2, field 2 is 7 to 0.1
```

And you want to get the value numbers (not the field names):

```
[[1, 5, 6.6],
 [2, 7, 0.1]]
```

You can do

```
data = np.fromregex('temp.txt', r'field1 is ([\d\.]+), field 2 is ([\d\.]+) to ([\d\.]+)', dtype='float')
```

The `[\d\.]+` matches any number, including decimal places, and the `()` tells numpy to use that result as a value.  You can also specify more complicated dtypes, such as having different columns have different types, as well as specifying column names to give a structured array.  That is covered in the documentation.

However, it is more complicated than other approaches when dealing with simple delimited or fixed-width data.